# Is there some shortcut method get route of model itself? or should I make it myself?

Tags: php, laravel

I'm middle of build my own site and in every form I just sick with type like

`{{ Route('something.something', ['something'=>$someting->id]) }}`

.. I know that I can make some shortcut method for (every) route (I want) but it feels somewhat .. I just don't like it. OCD......

Is there some build-in method or other awesome way like above??

Comment: What do you want actually? Please explain more!

Comment: You can, but you shouldn't. Just use `route()` helper as you do now.